# continuity of a functions involving trig functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

LEt $f$ be given as

$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{ \sin x - \sin y }{x-y}, & \text{if }\text{ $x \neq y $} \\
\cos x, & \text{if } x \text{ $=y$}
\end{cases}
$$

Notice when $y=x$, along the diagonal, $f = \cos x$ which is continuous everywhere. if $y \neq x$, then $f(x,y) = \frac{ \sin x - \sin y}{x-y}$, which I claim is continuous also everywhere. To show this, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. and take $(x,y), (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (t,t) \} $. We want to estimate

$$ \left| \frac{ \sin x - \sin y }{x-y} - \frac{ \sin u - \sin v }{u-v} \right|$$

given that $||(x,y) - (u,v)|| = \sqrt{ (x-u)^2 + (y-v)^2} < \delta $ for some $\delta > 0 $. How can I estimate so that we can choose an appropiate $\delta$ ?

Comment: I don't get it: **what** is the question, anyway?

Comment: showing $f$ is continuous everywhere

Comment: Hint: For any $x$, the limit of $\frac{\sin x-\sin y}{x-y}$ as $y$ approaches $x$ is a familiar quantity.

Comment: @Learner For any $\;x\neq y\;$ , the function's a fraction of two continuous functions and thus continuous as the denominator's function doesn't vanish. For $\;x=y\;$ follow Andre's hint.

Comment: Do you think that $\sin (x)-\sin (y)=2 \sin \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$ could be of any use ?

Comment: should be two cosines in the Right hand side??. Yea i was thinking about using this identity, but then how can I estimate my difference?

Comment: I'm not sure what the bounty-offerer dislikes about coffeemath's offer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only at points $(k,k)$ where the continuity is not immediate: If $(a,b)$ is a point for which $a \neq b$ then since sine is continuous, and the denominator $x-y$ approaches $a-b \neq 0$ as $(x,y) \to (a,b),$ the function $f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$. So it only remains to look at points $(a,b)$ for which $a=b$. Near these points, the piecewise function for $f$ sometimes uses the one rule, sometimes the other, depending on whether $x=y$. So some care has to be taken to argue about the limit as $(x,y) \to (k,k),$ and the following is a way to tack things down using the mean value theorem.

If $x \neq y$ then using the mean value theorem, we have
$$h(x,y)=\frac{\sin x - \sin y}{x-y}=\cos(c_{x,y}),$$ 
where $c_{x,y}$ is between $x$ and $y$ [i.e. if $x<y$ then $c_{x,y} \in (x,y)$ otherwise $c_{x,y} \in (y,x).$]

Then if $(x,y) \to (k,k)$ in any manner, we will certainly have either $f(x,y)=\cos(x)$ [when $x=y$] or else $f(x,y)=\cos(c_{x,y})$, and since $(x,y) \to (k,k)$ implies $|x-y| \to 0$ along with $x,y \to k$ we can use continuity of $\cos(x)$ to arrive at $\lim_{(x,y) \to (k,k)}f(x,y)=\cos(k).$

Comment: So, this means that $f$ continuous everywhere? correct?

Comment: @Learner Yes it does. At any point $(a,b)$ with $a \neq b$ the function $(\sin x-\sin y)/(x-y)$ is continuous, since as $(x,y) \to (a,b)$ the denominator goes to $a-b \neq 0$, and $\sin(u)$ is continuous for all $u$. So the only points left in question for your piecewise defined function are the points $(a,b)$ for which $a=b$ and these are the points $(k,k)$ addressed in my answer.